# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken error with another machine

Tags: google-signin

I use google api for sign-in on android app (Android Studio 1.5), sign in success and I can get token by GoogleAuthUtil.getToken (success with both genymotion emulator and real phone). But it is error getToken if I run project on other machines. Can you help me???